# How can I include PHP in a vBulletin style?

Tags: php, templates, coding-style, vbulletin

I'd like to use PHP in a vBulletin style/skin, yet when I do so, the PHP doesn't work.

By 'not work', I mean it's treated just as plain text. And if you look in the code you can see the PHP code (hidden, by Firefox - which is the behaviour you get if you put PHP code on a plain html page)

http://vapurl.com/h0kp3fqr8c - view source, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: So what php are you using, what happens when you use it/run it? What error messages are you getting? *What's the code*?

Comment: This needs a lot more information.

Comment: What script are you using that causes this behaviour? We need to know what you've *tried to do* (show us the code you've used, and where you've put it).

Comment: i've put the code just in the header bit of a style
you can view the site here: http://vapurl.com/h0kp3fqr8c

Comment: Stop using that temporary URL site and post the code segment itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't stick random PHP into the vBulletin templating system; it gives you some simple branching options in the form of

```
<if condition="$somevariable === $someothervariable">
    some text or HTML to be displayed
</else>
    some other text or HTML to be displayed
</if>
```

A good explanation of how the template conditional system works can be found [in the vBulletin manual here](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/template_conditionals).

Your short url appears to have expired, but if the code you wish to include is more complicated than that, you need to start looking into vBulletin [hooks](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/what_is_hook) and [plugins](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/what_is_plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're entering the correct PHP syntax, this may be occurring if you're trying to use any of the standard output methods.

If you are trying to use echo, print or any other similar output function, try wrapping all of your included PHP within ob functions.

Example:

```
ob_start();
   //PHP code I want to run goes here
   echo "Test this works?";
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this still didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

hooks /plugins are the best way of manipulating data before displaying it in the template. You can add as much php as you want in a plugin and then modify the template to output the results.